# How to add a progress bar to cryptsetup luksFormat?

Tags: process, encryption, cryptsetup

Example command.

```
cryptsetup --hash sha512 -c aes-xts-plain64 --key-size 512 luksFormat /dev/loop0
```

This can take quite a while for big files / on slow disks.

How to add a progress bar?

Answer (score 3):

There must be some kind of misunderstanding.

`cryptsetup luksFormat` doesn't do anything time consuming. It writes a `LUKS` header which, with one key slot is only like `128kb` or so in size. Writing that is pretty much an instant operation. The most time (around `1 second`) is spent on hashing your passphrase with many iterations to make bruteforce unviable. As such a progress bar is entirely unnecessary.

If that still hangs for whatever reason, maybe you should use `strace` or go all out with `gdb` to see where the hell it gets stuck...

---

Edit:

As an afterthought, it does grab some random data from either `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/random`. The latter might block for however long it takes to get entropy into the system. So that is a possible reason for it to hang. Unfortunately also no sane way to get a progress bar for this.

In order to speed this up, you can either add the `--use-urandom` parameter (if that does not help, entropy is not your problem), or wiggle your mouse around for a while, or do something about low entropy in general, like installing `haveged` or other entropy generators.